# How do I checkout a project from Codeplex when I do not have ANYTHING on my computer?

Tags: codeplex

I created the project and uploaded it to codeplex from my home computer. Everything works fine. Now I'm on the road on my laptop and I want to checkout my project.

Do I create a blank solution and then do the checkout? Do I have to checkout without creating any new projects (if so how?)?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what source control system your project is using.  It looks like CodePlex supports Mercurial, TFS, and SubVersion.  Instructions on how to connect are here:

http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Source%20control&referringTitle=CodePlex%20FAQ&ANCHOR#clients

Comment: [I wrote it here as a personal reminder] If the project uses SubVersion, you can usually checkout the repository using the url: `https://project_name.svn.codeplex.com/svn/`